# HTAccess mod rewrite issue using QSA

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to add a parameter to a URL but currently it isnt showing in the $_GET global. 
A snippet from my htaccess file is as below:

```
RewriteRule ^account/blogs/([0-9]+)/([^\s?]+)/?$ /account/blog.php?blogId=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in my php code i want to add a link such as:

> /account/blogs/1/ThisIsWhereTheTitleGoes?delete=1

The wildcard (any char but space) option is for the blog title as i never know what it would be. I know want to add a query string param on the end such as ?delete=1. I however dont want this as part of the rewrite.

Does anybody know how to so this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet would be to simply add get variables to the regex, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^account/blogs/([0-9]+)/([^\s?]+)/?(\?(.*))?$ /account/blog.php?blogId=$1&$4 [L,QSA]
```

This would rewrite

```
/account/blogs/1/ThisIsWhereTheTitleGoes?delete=1
```

to

```
/account/blog.php?blogId=1&delete=1
```

It would also support additional variables.