# Update: RewriteRule on virtual subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here i am again :(

got big problem hiks ... need HELP !!!

i have URL like

> http://www.foo.com/user/index.php?**uid=me&page=about**

and i want to change into like this

> http://me.foo.com/about

i already success to make virtual subdomain + wildcard + using this htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) user/index.php?uid=%2 [L]
```

but i do not know how to make **&page=about** appears on request

---

**UPDATE**

No body Answer this question :(

update, now i already have a solution, "with my try and error" :P

**"but" the htacces looks weird.** 
now, any one can fix this? or maybe what should i do ... this htaccess was RUN corecty

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ user/index.php?uid=%2&page=$2&subrequest=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ user/index.php?uid=%2&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) user/index.php?uid=%2 [L]
```

I really need your help masters :(

regard.

*Stecy >:(*

Comment: What does `RewriteRule (.*) user/index.php?uid=%2&page=$1 [L]` give you?

Comment: the result just blank :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it this helps:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)(?<!www)\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]*)$ user/index.php?uid=%1&page=$1 [L]
```

I'll be happy to explain what the above rules do if necessary.

Comment: ups sorry my bad :D ... on your htaccess page=$1 run corectly but blank on user/index.php?uid=%1 :(

Comment: The rule I posted will work for `http://www.me.foo.com/about` -> `http://www.me.foo.com/user/index.php?uid=me&page=about`. For other URLs then some tweaks are needed. Post the URL that is *blank*, I'll see if the problem can be worked around.

Comment: yes, http://www.me.foo.com/about was run correctly but http://www.me.foo.com not getting result on. i need both running :D thanks before

Comment: I've changed one character in the above rule (`+` -> `*`). Seems to work now.

Comment: huaaaaaaa you save my daaaay :* love you thank you thank youuuu :D .. seems i need learn more about this things :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using the QSA flag.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).foo.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) user/index.php?uid=%2 [QSA, L]
```

Check this out too > [HTAccess mod rewrite issue using QSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575850/htaccess-mod-rewrite-issue-using-qsa)